# Avoid automatically backup after restore from snapshot on RA3 Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-redshift, backup, snapshot

I have a Redshift cluster with ra3 node types.
When I restore the cluster from a snapshot it automatically triggers a new backup.

This is basically useless because it would be equal to the one used for the restore procedure.

This backup generates a huge load on the cluster causing many queries to fail or take really long time to be executed.

Can I delay this automatic backup? or disable it? or fully disable backups on my cluster?

Answer (score -1):

You can [schedule your maintenance window](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/modify-cluster.html) so that the backup happens only during that window.

example:

```
aws redshift modify-cluster --cluster-identifier mycluster --preferred-maintenance-window Sun:23:15-Mon:03:15
```

Comment: Looking at the doc it seems that the maintenance windows are related to cluster update activities, have you some specific reference about relationship with backups?